# How to empty the following array without causing in infinite look inside this Vue watch?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, infinite-loop

I'm watching a series of fields:

```
fields: {
  handler (fields) {
    Object.entries(fields).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      const field = fields[key]
      // field.errors = [] this will trigger an infinite look
      if (!field.validation) return
      const isRequired = field.validation.isRequired && !field.value
      if (isRequired) {
        field.errors[field.errors.length] = {
          errorType: 'isRequired',
          message: 'This field is required.'
        }
      }
    })
  },
  deep: true
}
```

Now I want to reset `field.errors` before the code runs ... the problem is that changing field, will change fields, and therefore, causing an infinite loop.

Comment: You don't mutate data inside data watcher! :)

Answer (score 1):

you can check if the errors array is already empty before setting them to a new empty array

```
if (Array.isArray(field.errors) && field.errors.length) 
    field.errors = []
```